# не могу открыть форму,что бы присутсвовали все типы данных

Tags: 1с

есть форма в которой пользователь выбирает любой документ из базы.Мне этот документ нужно преобразовать в текстовый файл.

```
&НаСервере
Функция ГенерДок()
     МассТипов= новый массив;
    МассТипов.Добавить(Справочники.ТипВсеСсылки());
    МассТипов.Добавить(Документы.ТипВсеСсылки());
    возврат МассТипов
КонецФункции

&НаКлиенте
Процедура ДокументНачалоВыбора(Элемент, ДанныеВыбора, СтандартнаяОбработка)
    Перем ДокСсылка;
    Документы=новый ОписаниеТипов(ГенерДок());
    ВвестиЗначение(ДокСсылка,,Документы);

КонецПроцедуры
```

Не могу никак открыть форму в "ввестизначение()",падает с ошибкой что мол отсутсвует способо ввести значение требуемого типа.Как решить?

Answer (score 0):

Создайте реквизит формы составного типа с необходимыми типами, например ДокументСсылка, СправочникСсылка и разместите его на форме.